# How I can convert this code from matlab to python?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, vector

I would like to convert this Matlab code

```
[data ones(N,1)]
```

to Numpy. How to do it efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

The numpy syntax is very similar.  To create an N by 1 array of ones, use:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> N = 5
>>> np.ones((N, 1))
array([[ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.]])
```

If you wanted 1 by N:

```
>>> np.ones((1, N))
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your issue also includes horizontal concatenation of array `data` and `ones(N, 1)` as done by `[data ones(N,1)]` in Matlab®.
So adding to the answers given by the others, you can use `np.hstack` to concatenate the two arrays.

Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> N = 5
>>> data = [[1],
... [2],
... [3],
... [4],
... [5]]
>>> np.hstack((data,np.ones((N,1))))
array([[ 1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  1.],
       [ 3.,  1.],
       [ 4.,  1.],
       [ 5.,  1.]])
```

`np.hstack` will concatenate the two arrays `data` and `np.ones(N,1)` horizontally(along axis=1).
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly, the function is named the same in numpy - [`np.ones()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html). It creates an array of the indicated shape filled with ones.